# Datepicker on AngularJS error with values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The thing I'm trying to do here is when a user selects a **StartDate** and an **EndDate** when he clicks on the previous arrow he should fetch data 7 days before every time in order to see the progress.

**JavaScript**:

```
 $scope.getDiffPrev = function(startDate, endDate, computeDiff) {
            var start  = startDate;
            var date1  = (start.getDate() -7);
            var month1 = (start.getMonth() +1);
            var year1  = start.getFullYear();
            var end    = endDate;
            var date2  = (end.getDate() -7);
            var month2 = (end.getMonth() +1);
            var year2  = end.getFullYear();
        $http.get('/admin/api/stats?start=' + date1 +'-'+ month1 +'-'+ year1 + '&end=' + date2 +'-'+ month2 +'-'+ year2 +'&computeDiff=true').success(function(data) {
            $scope.stats = data;
        });
    }
```

**HTML**:

```
   <label>From</label>
   <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy"  ng-model="startDate"/>
   <label>To</label>
   <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="endDate"/>
   <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="getDiffPrev(startDate, endDate, computeDiff)">&larr;</button>
```

Comment: i see: it was hard to write, it should be hard to understand ... what isn't working? ;) do you get any errors?

Comment: if date is 1-4-2014 is going to -6-4-2014

Comment: you have to put the date1 in module of the month's days, or you will fetch negative days. You need to do a method with an if for the getMonth return and in that put four cases 30 or 31 or 29 or 28 days

Comment: Can you give me a simple example cause i'm new to angular world

Comment: Use moment.js for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't we all love javascript's date? ;)

```
var start = angular.copy(startDate)
start.setDate(start.getDate() + computeDiff);
var date1 = start.getDate();
var month1 = start.getMonth() + 1; // i hate em for this one -.-
var year1 = start.getFullYear();
```

[and here an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl%3aFrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f?p=preview)

in the line `start.setDate(start.getDate() + computeDiff);` we use the Date()'s intern calculation to get the right date.

**EDIT**:
if you can add other libraries have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/)

```
moment().subtract('days', 7).format('yourFormatStringHere')
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much, you fix my day.Second can you suggest me any good way on how to refactor better this code cause there is a lot of code duplication.

Comment: glad i could help =) without external libraries i don't. javascripts Date() is really frustrating. if you can add other libraries, add moment.js to your project(s). it works in browser and server scripts too (eg node.js), has some nice functions like fromNow() ('answered 42 minutes ago') ... and more ;)